# Getting msg: Invalid parameter: PhoneNumber Reason: is not valid to publish to

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, sms, aws-sdk, amazon-sns

I was trying to send sms with some text using aws sns. When  I tried to, I got an error 'msg: Invalid parameter: PhoneNumber Reason: is not valid to publish to'. The code:

```
func SendSMS(snsCli *sns.SNS, phoneNumber string, message string) error {
    params := &sns.PublishInput{
        Message:     aws.String(message),
        PhoneNumber: aws.String(phoneNumber),
        MessageAttributes: map[string]*sns.MessageAttributeValue{
            "AWS.SNS.SMS.SenderID": {
                DataType:    aws.String("String"),
                StringValue: aws.String("ForTheRoad"),
            },
            "AWS.SNS.SMS.SMSType": {
                DataType:    aws.String("String"),
                StringValue: aws.String("Transactional"),
            },
        },
    }

    _, err := snsCli.Publish(params)
    if err != nil {
        awsErr := err.(awserr.Error)
        return fmt.Errorf("failed to send SMS, code: %s, msg: %s", awsErr.Code(), awsErr.Message())
    }

    return nil
}
```

Also, I tried to send sms without sdk, using aws sns website and cli and it worked properly. What can be the issue?

Edit: phone number I am using is "+380666055XXX"

Edit 2: Also, I'm fetching phone number from cognito, maybe that is the problem

Comment: You can probably log the phone number that it is trying to send to and check if it is valid.

Comment: I actually logged and it is valid

Comment: Which AWS region are you using here?

Comment: These are the regions which are supported to send sms sns https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-supported-regions-countries.html. If your region is here, then try to send it via `awc cli` to rule out issues with the `sns` itself. It could be issue with your code

Comment: I am using ap-southeast-1 region

Comment: @daivalo, Hav eyou tried `aws cli`? `aws sns publish \
    --message "Hello world!" \
    --phone-number +1-555-555-0100`.